# Copy column from one matrix to another

Tags: java, opencv

Is there any method in JavaCV to copy one column from one matrix to another? Both have the same length.

At the moment I use a simple iterator:

```java
    mat=cvCreateMat(image.rows(), image.cols(), CV_32FC1);
    CvMat col= cvCreateMat(1, image.cols(), CV_32FC1);
    cvGetCol(image, col, 0);
    for (int y = 0; y < image.cols(); y++) {
        mat.put(0, y, col.get(y));
    }
```

Comment: We can use `cvGetSubRect()` and then `cvCopy()` the submatrices, but I doubt it would be any faster than a straightforward loop on their raw buffers.

Comment: okay, it test it. But it isn't much faster :) thanks